# XML mal formatado

Tags: python, xml

Eu estou tentando ler alguns arquivos XML com o *Element Tree* do Python, porém um deles, quando vou fazer o *parser* me dá esse erro:

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token)

Essa é a linha que da o erro:

```
xml = ET.parse('./dados_apis/gamesdb/xml/infos_games/31758.xml')
```

Esse é arquivo XML: http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGame.php?id=31758

No Python, eu esto lendo do disco porque já está salvo.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver esse problema? Aparentemente é algum caractere especial, mas na abertura do XML está declarado ali a codificação UTF-8.

Comment: Poderia colocar na pergunta o seu código? Porque eu fiz um teste buscando direto do link e funcionou perfeitamente (https://repl.it/@acwoss/ScrawnyUnlinedFunctions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O XML do link é perfeitamente válido!

Porém, repare na Tag `<overview>`, onde existe um texto no qual aparece uma espécie de apóstrofo `’` após a palavra `Drake`, veja:

```
<Overview>Uncharted: The Nathan Drake Collection combines the three
PlayStation 3 blockbuster Nathan Drake adventures in one package.
Included are the single-player campaigns for Uncharted: Drake’s Fortune,
Uncharted 2: Among Thieves, and Uncharted 3: Drake’s Deception. Thanks to the
power of PlayStation 4 hardware, all three games have been upgraded to run at
1080p and 60fps with better lighting, textures, and models. Also added are a
range of improvements and additions including Photo Mode and new trophies
</Overview>
```

Esse caratere se trata de um [Right Single Quotation Mark](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2019) e pode estar em uma codificação diferente de `UTF-8`, causando esse erro.

Outra possibilidade, é que ao fazer a cópia do conteúdo do XML *online* para um arquivo local, a codificação do arquivo foi afetada, ocasionando o mesmo erro.